# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework.response'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In windows

```
from rest_framework import serializers
```

is working. but in 'view.py' file

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
```

is not working.

I checked 'setting.py' file , pip list and runserver state.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mood',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

```
$ pip list
Package               Version
--------------------- -------
asgiref               3.3.1
Django                3.1.6
pip                   21.0.1
Python-Rest-Framework 0.3.14
pytz                  2021.1
setuptools            41.2.0
six                   1.15.0
sqlparse              0.4.1
(venv)
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework.response'
```

Comment: in the question, you wrote `rest_framework` wrong (second import) did you check that is not just a typo in the import?

Comment: sure. i check the typo. but the same error occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed `python-rest-framework` not `django-rest-framework`. your import statements are correct, but not the installed package.

> Python-Rest-Framework 0.3.14

Use this to install DRF:

```sh
pip install djangorestframework
```

Comment: ```in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django' ``` when  i installed the package , sentence on the left is occur. So I use ```Python-Rest-Framework``` package.

Comment: The package you installed is unrelated to `django-rest-framework`, install `djangorestframework` package, and then update your post with new errors and full traceback.

Comment: i try again. (all of the files deleted and then  installed with the ```djangorestframework```). and your answer is right! Thank you for helping me!

Comment: You're welcome, happy coding and welcome to the community!

Answer (score 0):

You Should Install Django REST framework but you have Installed Python Rest framework.
To install Django Rest framework please Install the rest framework with below code.

```
pip install djangorestframework
```

Comment: ```in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django' ``` when  i installed the package , sentence on the left is occur. So I use ```Python-Rest-Framework``` package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pip to install the restframework module:

```
pip3 install djangorestframework
```